# Из трех инпутов достать значение двух

Tags: php, post, form, submit

Есть три инпута. Мне нужно значение двоих из них. Их значение выводит, но работать с `name_post` при перезагрузки я могу, а с `date_post` - нет.

```
$posts = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE type = 'official' ORDER BY date DESC");
     if($posts->num_rows > 0){
        echo '<table>';
        while($postsF = $posts->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<tr><td><form id="post" method="post">';
            echo '<input class="namePost" name="name_post" type="submit" value="'.$postsF['name'].'"></input>';
            echo '<input class="creatorPost" name="creator_post" type="submit" value="'.$postsF['creator'].'"</input>';
            echo '<input class="datePost" name="date_post" type="submit" value="'.$postsF['date'].'"</input>';
            echo '</form></td>';
            }
        echo '</table>';
    }
```

.

```
if(isset($_POST['name_post'])){
    $namePost = $_POST['name_post'];
    $datePost = $_POST['date_post'];

    $id = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM post WHERE name = '$namePost' AND date = '$datePost'");
    $id = mysqli_fetch_array($id);
    $id = $id['id'];

    $creatorPost = $mysqli->query("SELECT creator FROM post WHERE id = '$id'");
    $creatorPost = mysqli_fetch_array($creatorPost);
    $creatorPost = $creatorPost['creator'];

    $_SESSION['nameOfPost'] = $namePost;
    $_SESSION['dateOfPost'] = $datePost;
    $_SESSION['creatorOfPost'] = $creatorPost;

    header('Location: officialPost.php?'.$id); exit();
}
```

.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в форме несколько инпутов с `type="submit"`, на сервер в запросе передается только значение нажатого.

```
<input class="datePost" name="date_post" type="hidden" ...
```

Comment: йомайо, точно, спасибо, а я голову ломаю) переписал код и всё работает)

Comment: @BODN4R На здоровье. Успехов! Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".

Answer (score 0):

Поменя на GET запрос.Тогда у тебя будут 2 переменные ввидну ,ну и передадуться.Но у тебя не весь код,судить сложно ,возможно у тебя в форме самой ошибка ,ты ее не правельно офрмил.В принцип кода верен ,и передача переменных должна быть,но ты работаешь на другой странице по этой причине,передается 1 пременная ,вторая теряется,сделай GET.